# Contour integrals involving Tan and Cos

Tags: complex-analysis

My difficulty is making sure I'm looking at the appropriate poles.

(1)$\oint_C \tan{z}$ where $C$ is the circle $|z|=2$
(2)$\oint_C \frac{1+z}{1-\cos{z}}$ where $C$ is the circle $|z|=7$
(3)$\oint_C \frac{dz}{1+z^4}$ where $C$ is $-2\leq z\leq2$ and the semicircle in the upper half plane $|z|=2$.

(1)  For this one I believe the poles are at $z=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$.  The answer I got for this was $-4i\pi$.
(2)  With this one, I believe the poles are at $0$, $-2\pi$, and $2\pi$.  For an answer I got $12i\pi$.
(3)  This one actually threw me off a bit.  But I believe the only two poles I need to worry about are $e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}$ and $e^{\frac{3i\pi}{4}}$.  For this one I got $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Are these answers (including poles) correct?

Comment: Why do you "believe"? Do you understand your computations?

Comment: I'm just not confident in my answers at this point.  I'm sort of doing a self-study of complex to occupy my summer.

Comment: Let's discuss then, it'll be more fruitful than a simple confirmation. How did you find the poles for $(1)$?

Comment: I just looked for where $\cos{z}=0$ where $|z|<2$.  Similarly for the second one, but I checked where $\cos{z}=1$ for $|z|<7$.

Comment: That's exactly what you have to do ; since $\sin(z)$ and $\cos(z)$ are holomorphic over $\mathbb C$ (the radius of convergence of their Taylor expansion around $0$ is infinite), the only reason this function would have a pole is if the denominator vanishes. You know you have to solve $(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2 = 0$ to find the zeros of $\cos(z)$, do you? It involves solving an (easy) quadratic which tells you that the zeros are indeed at $\pi/2 + k \pi$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: All those zeros of $\cos(z)$ will be simple zeros (the derivative of $\cos(z)$ is non-zero at those points), so computing the residues is easy in this case ; the poles have order $1$, so you multiply $\tan(z)$ by $z$ and you compute the limit $z \tan(z)$ as $z$ goes to the pole. If this is what you've done then you've understood everything perfect :D does it make everything else more clear?